# Как пересоздать Главный Activity из другого Activity

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что мне нужно добавить функцию переключения языков в `SettingsActivity`. В настройке при клике применить другой язык везде переводится нормально, кроме `MainActivity`. Так как он не пересоздался. Так вот, при клике мне нужно пересоздать `MainActivity` чтобы новый язык применился.

Попробовал:

```
1) Intent intent = getIntent();
   finish();
   startActivity(intent);
```

cannot resolve method `getIntent()`;

```
2) MainActivity.recreate()
```

non-static method `recreate()`;

```
3) Попробовал создать метод в самом MainActivity:

public void reload() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

но `SettingsActivity` его не видит, так как он не метод не `статичный`. А если сделать его `статичным`, то опять же `non-static method getIntent()`

Как решить эту проблему, подскажите. Не знаю даже куда копать!!!

Comment: а если просто onCreate(null);?

Comment: Не совсем понял? Куда?

Comment: Так, возможно я тоже не понял вопрос... Вы переходите из MainActivity в SettingsActivity, там переключаете язык, и возвращаетесь в MainActivity, так?

Comment: Да, верно!.....

Comment: Как вараинт попробуйте запускать SettingsActivity механизмом startActivityForResult, и в случае смены языка прокидывать обратно какой нибудь ключ типа isNeedRefreshAvitvity = true, и в MainActivity в переопределенном методе onActivityResult считывать его, и есть true - вызывать метод onCreate(null)

Comment: Ммм, у меня совсем все плохо с Activity life cycle, но я помню, что Ativity уходя под другую активити и выходя на вершину стека из под нее вызывает методы, точно не помню, но пусть это будет onPause и onResume. Можно же заменить все необходимые тексты в этих методах?

Comment: Да, попробовал так: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        recreate();
    }
завершается, но обратно не запускается! Может это потому что до MainActivity есть и StartActivity? который после 3 секунд автоматически запускает MainActivity и сам завершается

Comment: Может хардкодом, вроде как textView.setText(textForTextViewByLanguage())

Comment: В Drawer Menu все равно язык останется без изменений...

Comment: А пытались Log.d засунуть в onCreate? Может она перерисовывается, только чего то не хватает

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так.

В `MainActivity` при запуске `SettingsActivity` используйте флаги, очищающие таск (все активности закроются):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity (intent) ;
```

Ну а из `SettingsActivity` запустите `MainActivity` через интент обычно.

Comment: Открывается SettingsActivity и через полсекунды программа вылетает без ошибок

Comment: @Omuradil У меня запускалась вторая активность без вылета. А без этих флагов нет проблем?

Comment: Да, без флагов открывает нормально

Comment: @Omuradil Наверное, SettingActivity не может существовать самостоятельно без вызвавшей ее активности.

Comment: Да, скорее всего...

Answer (score 1):

1. Возможно вам не обязательно пересоздавать активити, попробуйте просто обновить его данные.
2. Способ, который вы описали (с помощью статичного метода) у вас не пройдет, так как все необходимые для пересоздания активити методы - не статичны.

Создание интерфейса `Listener` в `Application` (или где-нибудь еще) и его реализация внутри активити, которое нужно обновить, может решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как в Application?

Answer (score -3):

Может в `onResume` того активити, который надо перерисовать написать `startActivity(getIntent())`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

Comment: Данный код вызовет зацикливание, то есть бесконечно будет открываться и затем закрываться данная активити. Поставленную задачу не решает ни коим образом.